# <t:selectmanycheckbox> valueChangeListener

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

I have a problem with my < t:selectmanycheckbox> and  valueChangeListener. It works on FireFox and Chrome but not on Internet Explorer.
If I want to execute "processValueChange", I have to click on 2 checkboxes because if I click on 1 checkbox, the method is not executed. I don't understand x_X

```
<a4j:region>   
    <t:selectManyCheckbox    
        id="selectManyCheckboxParent"    
        forceId="false"  
        forceIdIndex="false"    
        layout="spread"    
        immediate="true"  
        value="#{resultBean.checkBoxesListParentSelectedValues}"  
        valueChangeListener="#{resultBean.processValueChange}">   
        <f:selectItems id="selectItemsParent" value="#{resultBean.checkBoxesListParent}" />   
    </t:selectManyCheckbox>   
</a4j:region>

public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {   
 buttonRendered= (... ? true : false)
  }
```

Anybody has an explanation ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Resolved!

I'm using now "a4j:support" with the event "onclick" instead of "onchange". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I'm using now "a4j:support" with the event "onclick" instead of "onchange". :)